# Если в конструктор singletone-класса кидать контекст приложения, утечка памяти невозможна?

Tags: java, android, шаблоны-проектирования, context

А главное как(сделать это правильно)? Здесь предположение о отсутствии утечки 
 из-за того, что контекст приложения тоже вроде как один. Контекст мне нужен в других методах Presenter-a, но студия ругается, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что может быть утечка памяти, но(!) я то знаю что экземпляров application context, которые принимаются от класса MyApplication,- всего один, так что можно игнорировать предупреждение? или я вообще ничего не понимаю

Singletone-класс, где нужен контекст приложения

```
public class MyPresenter implements Contract.ContractPresenter{
    private Context mContext;

    private static MyPresenter presenterInstance;
    private Contract.ContractView mViewInstance;

    private MyPresenter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static synchronized void initPresenterInstance(Context context) {
        if (presenterInstance == null) {
            presenterInstance = new MyPresenter(context);
        }
    }
    public static MyPresenter getPresenterInstance() {
        return presenterInstance;
    }
}
```

и Application-класс

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyPresenter.initPresenterInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }

}
```

Comment: правильно сделать: передавать контекст в нужные функции, и не хранить его в статике

Comment: @Jarvis_J , насколько я понял, статические контексты все таки могут вызывать утечки памяти, а чтоб сделать контекст доступным в другом классе, его в MyApplication нужно будет объявлять статическим

Comment: Тоесть как его вообще можно получить в не activity-классе

Comment: Блин, ну правильно жеш! в этом ответе написано, что с application context можно делать вообще что угодно,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498669/needing-context-in-non-activity-classes?rq=1 , я правильно понимаю?

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что приведенный выше код есет  в себе Singletone паттерн? У Вас публичный конструктор. И зачем Вы сделали переменную, несущую объект presenter'а статичной? Вам бы стоило написать get метод под это поле.

Comment: @KostyaM
Вот про конструктор видимо еще нужно почитать, потому что разницы между публичным и приватным конструкторами я не ощущаю, а вот насчет статичного presenter-a, в простых примерах синглетонов это нормальное дело. А getPresenter есть, я его не указал в примере,но уже добавил. Тогда и в конструкторе мне нужно вместо самой переменной использовать getPresenter?

Comment: Идея синглтона в том, чтобы его нельзя было создать из вне. Для этого конструкторы делают приватными. Инициализируется синглотон припомощи метода getInstance, именно он возвращает объект синглтона, и если нужно, инициализирует его

Comment: Кстати, андроид студия может сгенерировать шаблон синглтона, нажмите new java class -и в выпадающем списке выберите singletone, можете глянуть, как оно ввглядит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79607/discussion-between---and-kostya-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе длительных рассуждения, я решил, что я знаю ответ. Есть два выхода из сложившейся ситуации. 
1)Использовать Dagger 2, как в  [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057273/android-singleton-with-global-context) примере. 
2) НЕ ДЕЛАТЬ ТАК, а если быть точнее, то выполнять всю работу Dagger'а ручками. А именно, если требуется работа с Context или подобными классами, создавать дополнительный класс (Не Singleton). Сам Singleton же должен держать в себе ссылку на этот класс. Вырисовывается вот такая картина:
Сам Singleton

```
public class Singleton {
private static final Singleton ourInstance = new Singleton();
private static SomeService ss;
public static Singleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if(ss==null){
        ss=new SomeService(context);
    }
    return ourInstance;
}

private Singleton() {
}

public SomeService getSs() {
    return ss;
}
```

}

Сервис, работающий с Context, ссылка на объект которого хранится в Singleton

```
public class SomeService {
    private int result=0;
    SomeService(Context context){
        result=doSomeBusyJob(context);
    }
    int doSomeBusyJob(Context context){
        return 0;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Ну и затем уже делать как-то вот так

```
Singleton.getInstance(applicationContext).getSs().getResult()
```

В таком случае, мы убиваем двух зайцев: не допускаем случайного размножения класса SomeService, впринципе, для чего и нужен Singleton паттерн, а во-вторых, не храним в глобальном окружении синглтона такие классы, как Context, надеюсь, Вам это поможет решить Вашу задачу

Comment: Вполне даже элегантно! Но вот если понадобится расположить в SomeService два разных метода doSomeBusyJob1 и 2, (оба работают с Context) , то нужно либо делать приватную переменную контекста в классе, и при инстансе обьекта класса инициализировать контекстную переменную,  или делать так `Singleton.getInstance(applicationContext).getSs().getResult2(applicationContext))`

Comment: В singletone SomeService-a может жеш храниться контекст, принятый из конструктора, это ж синглтон, ничего не будет(?)

Comment: Тоесть я понимаю, что моделей может быть больше, если больше всяких задач, тип doGetModel,doPostModel, к примеру, но это можно ведь и абстрагировать и в этом классе содержать нужные методы. Хотя тут на помощь нам может придти наследование и есть одна идея...

Comment: идею на потом, а я вот подумал, - методы типа getResult вызываются в тех же местах, что и инстанс синглтонов и прочьего(не всегда,нужно обдумать этот момент),так почему бы не инстанциировать их без каких либо контекстов, а вот их методы вызывать передавая в них контекст. Вот клик на кнопку "скачать" в MainActivity, - из onclicklistener-a вызываем метод презентера runDownload(this.context), (передали ему контекст) , runDownload вызывает метод Model.download(context)  передав ему переданный ему (полученный им(методом runDownload)) контекст. Что скажете? no memory leaks, no архитектурных проблем?

Comment: Так делать, конечно, можо и может являться вариантом, но только в случае, когда не нужен целый огромный объект с кучей методов работающих с Context'ом, ибо это очень энергозатратно.

Comment: На самом деле, Сервис можно и модифицировать, продумать немного иную логику, но по крайней мере, такой способ работает, хоть и не подходит под все ситуации

Comment: вот про энергозатратность и куча методов у обьекта не совсем понял. Это если у presenter есть ~10 методов, работающих с контекстом? И почему и в чем проявляется энергозатратность?

Comment: Просто хорошо один раз проинициализировать класс с Context, чем 10 раз передавать его в виде параметров, есл иделать так, то сама необходимость сервиса отпадает. Но в данном случае, когда речь идет о Presenter'е будет правильнее с ним

Comment: Ну вобще да, это даже выглядит как то несерьезно с кучей контекстов, но иначе способа вызвать отдельный метод presenter-a с контекстом не  будет, все в конструкторе. Можно сделать класс Presenter, в нем подклассы типа Presenter.DownloadFile и Presenter.UploadFile(можно ведь?), но тогда сколько методов,-  столько и экземпляров. А если у меня мильйон методов?) Ну хз, пока меня не послали...делать на dagger'e, сделаю уже как надумал, не без Вашей помощи(!), спасибо большое